# setContentView() being initialised, not called

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I'm following a tutorial on DataBinding and it replaces:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` with

`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`

[image]

I'm wondering how setting the value of `binding` to an instance with `setContentView()` sets the content view. Because it's not calling `setContentView()`.

I'm also wondering how the `ActivityMainBinding` object is involved in the following assignment:

`binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed the source code? :)
When you're calling

`DataBindingUtil.setContentView(@NonNull Activity activity, int layoutId)`

it calls

`DataBindingUtil.setContentView(@NonNull Activity activity, int layoutId, @Nullable DataBindingComponent bindingComponent)`

this method internally calls

`activity.setContentView(layoutId);`.

Read more [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/e4cd38824a6627b9fef229c549c636e35ad63b5f/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java)

And also if your view has `id` (like R.id.done_button) you don't have to call `findViewById` method. It should be available through the binding object, like

`binding.doneButton`

Comment: Thanks. But isn't is assigning a value? (`binding = ...`) not calling it...

Comment: It sets content view internally, creates a binding object and returns it to the `binding` variable. The assigning itself not calling it.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know when a class like this is calling it internally?

Comment: @Zorgan, it calls it right when you call `DataBindingUtil.setContentView`... Press `Ctrl` and click on the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` method in your IDE and it will guide you to this method internals.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of what the `T` (type) could be in `public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T setContentView`?

Comment: It could be any class that is extended from `ViewDataBinding`, in your case it will be  `ActivityMainBinding`.